# Is it possible to rebase individual changesets to an earlier point in history?

Tags: mercurial, rebase

Here's what our tree looks like right now:

```
@ branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
o branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
o branch: default
| bug fix C
|
|
o branch: default
| bug fix B
|
|
o branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
o branch: default
| bug fix A
|
|
o branch: default
| tag: ReleaseV1.0
|
|
 ... ancient history
```

Here's what I'd like our tree to look like:

```
@ branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
o branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
o branch: default
| new feature work
|
|
|
| o branch: V1.1Fixes
| | bug fix C
| |
| |
| o branch: V1.1Fixes
| | bug fix B
| |
| |
| |
| o branch: V1.1Fixes
| | bug fix A
| |
|/
o branch: default
| tag: ReleaseV1.0
|
|
 ... ancient history
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I would use the [`transplant` extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension). Transplanted changesets don't move in the `fixes` branch but also stay in the development (`default`) branch. I don't really guess what are those "new feature work" commits, but I smell that you are trying to `transplant`.

Not removing your "new feature work" commits, the history graph would look like that:

```
  o branch: V1.1Fixes
  | transplanted bug fix C
  |
  |
@ | branch: default
| | new feature work
| |
| |
| o branch: V1.1Fixes
| | transplanted bug fix B
| |
| |
o | branch: default
| | new feature work
| |
| |
o | branch: default
| | bug fix C
| |
| |
o | branch: default
| | bug fix B
| |
| |
| o branch: V1.1Fixes
| | transplanted bug fix A
| |
| |
o | branch: default
| | new feature work
| |
| |
o | branch: default
| | bug fix A
| |
|/
o branch: default
| tag: ReleaseV1.0
|
|
 ... ancient history
```

If those "new feature work" commit are just dummy flag-commits to retain the changes in the development tree, you don't need them anymore if you `transplant`. I kept them as if they were some after-development documentation, changelog update,...

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [RebaseProject](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseProject) and [Rebase Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/RebaseExtension). You may also use [Transplant Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/TransplantExtension) to apply a patch from a branch to one or more other braches (to get something similar to what [Django](https://bitbucket.org/django/django/changesets) history looks).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible (as long as the new features does not depends on changes made on bug fix changesets), but it is not recommended.
This can be quite easily achieved by importing your changesets in MQ, up to tag ReleaseV1.0 and then re-commit then on the correct branch.
However, keep in mind that doing so, you'll change the history, which means that all the hashes of these changesets will be modified, which means that you'll screw all the users that have already pulled your latest changes.

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely something I want to avoid. I should mention in my question that this has already been distributed into the wild, so to speak.